# Debian Buster: How to start ZFS after open-iscsi in systemd

Tags: debian, zfs, systemd, open-iscsi

I have Debian 10 (Buster) installed and have added ZFS from Backports. I have 4 iSCSI-LUNs that I use as disks for ZFS. Each LUN holds a separate zpool.

So far the ZFS setup works. But the system is not reboot-stable. Sometimes after reboot all ZFS volumes are restored and mounted correctly, sometimes not. I think that happens, because ZFS does not wait for iSCSI-completion.

I tried:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.d/after-open-iscsi.conf
```

```
[Unit]
After=open-iscsi.service
BindsTo=open-iscsi.service
```

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain zfs-import-cache.service
```

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

zfs-import-cache.service +1.602s
└─open-iscsi.service @2min 1.033s +286ms
  └─iscsid.service @538ms +72ms
    └─network-online.target @536ms
      └─ifup@eth0.service @2min 846ms
        └─apparmor.service @2min 748ms +83ms
          └─local-fs.target @2min 745ms
            └─exports-kanzlei.mount @2min 3.039s
              └─local-fs-pre.target @569ms
                └─keyboard-setup.service @350ms +216ms
                  └─systemd-journald.socket @347ms
                    └─system.slice @297ms
                      └─-.slice @297ms
```

This does not solve my problems. Probably the iSCSI stuff is not ready but already systemd-activated and therefore ZFS does not find its devices.

Currently the only very dirty workaround is to put some rules in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
systemctl start zfs-import-cache.service
systemctl start zfs-mount.service
systemctl start zfs-share.service
systemctl start zfs-zed.service

zfs mount -a
```

This works, but I want a clean solution.

What I really do not understand and what drives me crazy is that in Debian there do exist `/etc/init.d/scriptname` and also `systemd` unit files. Which one is used? sysvinit or systemd? Why are both provided? Which ones are the better ones?

So currently I feel I have a not stable boot process here.

Comment: This is exactly my present question. I cannot find a recommended solution for this. The systemd manual provides enough info for me to be able to design attempts at solutions, but what I've tried thus far doesn't work. If you've figured it out, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of doing this is probably to use a `udev` rule, but I don't know `udev` well enough.
This is my present workaround (please tell me how to do better):

1. Create a service for the iSCSI disk device you need to wait on (`/dev/sdb1`, in my case):

   `$ sudo EDITOR=vim systemctl edit --force --full dev-sdb1.service`
2. In the service definition, make ZFS depend on it.
3. In the service definition, make it wait for the device to be available.

3 is the tricky part. What I have is this:

```
[Unit]
Description="Monitor the existence of /dev/sdb1"
Before=zfs-import-cache.service
# Requires=dev-sdb1.device
# After=dev-sdb1.device
# I thought this would wait for the device to become available.
# It doesn't, and there appears to be no way to actually do so.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'while [ ! -e /dev/sdb1 ]; do sleep 10; done'
# pathetic

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
RequiredBy=zfs-import-cache.service
```

Obviously it would be better to do this without a shell script to poll for the device. Having read the documentation regarding device units and the answers to these Stack Exchange questions:

- [Why are there no device unit files in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571107/why-are-there-no-device-unit-files-in-debian)
- [Make systemd service wait for a device, generically](https://superuser.com/questions/1469766/make-systemd-service-wait-for-a-device-generically)

and verified that `dev-sdb1.device` exists after booting, I expected to just be able to make the `zfs-import-cache.service` wait for `/dev/sdb1` by adding the rules

```
After=dev-sdb1.device
Requires=dev-sdb1.device
```

to its definition. That doesn't work; it will say the service `failed with result 'dependency'`, whatever that means. I suppose the `dev-sdb1.device` doesn't exist yet, `systemd` doesn't know it will be created soon, and I cannot find a directive to say "just wait for it".

Alternative approaches:

1. Use a path unit instead of a shell script to wait for the device. I haven't tried this.
2. [Add a `udev` rule matching `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdb1` (if possible) to explicitly make its device unit available](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2012-January/160917.html). I haven't tried this; I don't see why it would help (the device unit is already being created) and I don't know how to figure out if this would have any other effects on device initialization and break anything as a result.